# How to Pass Token from server to client in nodejs-Express-passport application

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, web-applications, passport.js

I am using Nodejs+Express+passport.js. I have done the authentication and have token server side. Now i want to call some API on the client side javascript file(to populate the lists on html page) and want to use that token there. What the Best possible way to do that ? Should i store the token in user object and pass it along the routes, so that its available in the jade/ejs  file and use it from there ?

Comment: Should i store the token in user object and pass it along the routes, so that its available in the jade/ejs file and use it from there ? The answer is yes.